# Is it possible to display characters differently from what is stored on disk in Eclipse editor?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

We're developing an Eclipse plugin.

When the user types `<=` I would like to *display* a left-arrow UTF character `⇐` instead.
The file on disk still needs to contain the original "less than,equals" symbols, because that is what the programming language prescribes.

In other contexts, in the same editor, I might want to display the same character sequence `<=` as unicode less or equal `≤`. This would help the user understand how the compiler interprets the sequence `<=`, depending on the context. Again, the document (and file) should not be changed, only the way we display it.

What is the easiest way to do this? Note that we're already on xText, so we use the editor provided by xText.

Comment: An Eclipse editor can certainly do this but I don't know xtext so I don't know if the editor it produces can achieve this.

Comment: @greg-449 Can you share how to do this in a "standard" editor? Perhaps we can use the same techniques in an Eclipse Xtext editor.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse text editors normally use an object implementing `IDocument` (usually also the numerous `IDocumentExtensionXX` interfaces) often by extending the `AbstractDocument` class.

This document class provides the text that the editor displays and is updated with the changes the user makes, so it should be able to manage converting between the file and display representations.